# connectedComponentsWithStats was not declared in this scope Qt creator c++ opencv 3.0.0

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

Estoy utilizando una raspberry pi y estoy programando en qt c++, el problema que tengo es que me muestra este error ya mencionado y en esta parte del codigo

```
int n_labels = connectedComponentsWithStats(
        bw, label_img, stats, centroids, 8);
```

Alguna idea de que podria ser?

mas aparte tengo instalado opencv3.0.0

y estas librerías son las que tengo declaradas

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <QFile>
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>
#include <valarray>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <QVector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
```

Comment: No será que se te ha olvidado incluir el `namespace`, `cv::connectedComponentsWithStats`? Si no es eso probablemente no estés incluyendo la cabecera que incorpora la declaración de la función

Comment: Sabes cual es esa cabecera que mencionas ?